# Armazenar CSS em string

Tags: javascript, css, conversão

```
.ql-snow .ql-tooltip{background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #ccc;box-shadow:0 0 5px #ddd;color:#444;padding:5px 12px;white-space:nowrap}.ql-snow .ql-tooltip::before{content:"Visit URL:";line-height:26px;margin-right:8px}.ql-snow .ql-tooltip input[type=text]{display:none;border:1px solid #ccc;font-size:13px;height:26px;margin:0;padding:3px 5px;width:170px}.ql-snow .ql-tooltip a.ql-preview{display:inline-block;max-width:200px;overflow-x:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;vertical-align:top}.ql-snow .ql-tooltip a.ql-action::after{border-right:1px solid #ccc;content:'Edit';.ql-snow .ql-tooltip a.ql-action2::after{border-right:1px solid #ccc;content:"Cancel";}
```

Existe algum site online que converte HTML, ou CSS em string, para jogar tudo dentro de uma variável?  Por exemplo:

Coloco no form isso:

```
body {
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

Ele me retornaria algo como isso, fazendo toda tratativa de escape:

```
var css = 'body{margin:0;padding:0}';
```

Se fosse em PHP, eu faria assim:

```
$var =  <<<END
   .ql-snow .ql-tooltip{background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #ccc;box-shadow:0 0 5px #ddd;color:#444;padding:5px 12px;white-space:nowrap}.ql-snow .ql-tooltip::before{content:"Visit URL:";line-height:26px;margin-right:8px}.ql-snow .ql-tooltip input[type=text]{display:none;border:1px solid #ccc;font-size:13px;height:26px;margin:0;padding:3px 5px;width:170px}.ql-snow .ql-tooltip a.ql-preview{display:inline-block;max-width:200px;overflow-x:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;vertical-align:top}.ql-snow .ql-tooltip a.ql-action::after{border-right:1px solid #ccc;content:'Edit';.ql-snow .ql-tooltip a.ql-action2::after{border-right:1px solid #ccc;content:"Cancel";}
END;
```

Preciso fazer isso para gerar um PDF:

```
var valor1 = 'aqui viria o css minificado com as aspas escapada';
var valor2 = 'mais CSS aqui...';

 $('.main').prepend('<style type="text/css">' + [
                 valor1,
                 valor2
              ].join('') + '</style>');
```

**OBS:** Minha pergunta está clara, o problema é que as pessoas não entenderam, e por isso estou tendo que que acrescentar mais informação, para esclarecer para aqueles que não conseguem compreender o que está óbvio:

> 1 - Não estou procurando uma solução para minificar o CSS
>
> 2 - Estou procurando uma solução para jogar o CSS minificado dentro de uma variável com uma string dentro de aspas.
>
> 3 - Não quero fazer a string manualmente (ou seja, não quero digitá-la), quero gerar uma string no formato de string e não do seu valor.

Comment: Não é capturar o valor e remover as quebras de linha e espaços?

Comment: Sim, eu preciso desse css em valor... Mas não só esse... manualmente, dá muito trampo.

Comment: Eu tentei [nesse site](https://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html), mas não achei nada.

Comment: Não dá trabalho, veja a resposta do jbueno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz este exemplo me baseando na resposta do @jbueno tentando mexer no que eu acho que era sua expectativa. Veja se te atende.

```js
document.getElementById('btn-remover').addEventListener('click', fnClick);
var str = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0].firstChild.data;
var textArea = document.getElementById('txt-css');

function fnClick() {
  var val = str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
  console.log(val);
  textArea.innerHTML += val;
}
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt-css"></textarea> <br>
<button id="btn-remover">Remover</button>
```

### ESCAPANDO ASPAS

Aqui o código troca todos os `"` por `\"`:

```js
document.getElementById('btn-remover').addEventListener('click', fnClick);
var str = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0].firstChild.data;
var textArea = document.getElementById('txt-css');

function fnClick(){
  var val = str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
  var newVal = val.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
  console.log(newVal);
  textArea.innerHTML += newVal;
}
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
}
.escaped {
  content: "http://urlAleatório.com";
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt-css"></textarea> <br>
<button id="btn-remover">Remover</button>
```

### DENTRO DE ASPAS

Aqui, além de trocar as aspas, a variável é criada já dentro das `' '`.

```js
document.getElementById('btn-remover').addEventListener('click', fnClick);
var str = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0].firstChild.data;
var textArea = document.getElementById('txt-css');

function fnClick(){
  var val = str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
  var escVal = val.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
  var newVal = "'" + escVal + "'";
  console.log(newVal);
  textArea.innerHTML += newVal;
}
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
}
.escaped {
  content: "http://urlAleatório.com";
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt-css"></textarea> <br>
<button id="btn-remover">Remover</button>
```

### FOLHA DE ESTILO SEPARADA

Esta opção funcionará **apenas usando uma folha de estilo separada** e fará tudo o que a última opção faz. **Esta função também irá substituir todas as aspas simples em aspas duplas escapadas**. Se estiver fazendo offline, o Chrome pode dar erro de segurança pois ele não deixa o js fazer esta função. Nesse caso, você precisaria iniciar o Chrome com websecurity disabled, ou fazer o teste com arquivos online.

```js
document.getElementById('btn-remover').addEventListener('click', fnClick);
var textArea = document.getElementById('txt-css');
var str;
$.ajax({
  url: 'style.css',
  success: function(data) {
    str = data;
  }
});

function fnClick() {
  var val = str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
  var escVal = val.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
  var escVal = escVal.replace(/'/g, '\\"');
  var newVal = "'" + escVal + "'";
  console.log(newVal);
  textArea.innerHTML += newVal;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<textarea id="txt-css"></textarea> <br>
<button id="btn-remover">Remover</button>
```

Comment: A sua resposta é a que mais se aproxima, porém, vc removeu as aspas, eu gostaria de tratar ela para este formato quando for as dupla:  \" neste formato.

Comment: @IvanFerrer Não entendi. Você gostaria que a variável já viesse com aspas em sua volta? Tipo: `'body { repare nas aspas: 0px; }'` ? Seria isso?

Comment: @IvanFerrer Ou você quer transformar todas as `"` em `\"` na string criada?

Comment: @IvanFerrer Botei um EDIT escapando as aspas. Vê se é isso.

Comment: `{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 30,
  "colno": 16
}`

Comment: @IvanFerrer Você leu minha descrição? Este último exemplo é para folhas de estilo separadas. Logicamente não funciona aí. Pegue o exemplo e use no seu PC com sua folha de estilo e substitua no código o `url: 'style.css',` pelo caminho e o nome da sua folha de estilo. Coloquei 4 exemplos. Algum deve ser o que procura. xD

Comment: ok, vou testar aqui.

Comment: Testei aqui, ele emputou o CSS no textarea, ele até colocou barra invertidas nas aspas, só que continua quebrando, pois tem aspas duplas e aspas simples, não funcionou. Acredito que está invertido..., seria aspas duplas não, para este caso... a string, fecha com aspas duplas?

Comment: @IvanFerrer Completa pra mim. O que exatamente você quer que aconteça com cada tipo de aspas? Aspas simples: `'` devem virar o que? Aspas duplas: `"` devem ser o que?

Comment: Nesse exemplo eu fiz com que já tivesse aspas simples no início e no fim, se bem entendi, você quer que eu transforme todas as aspas internas em `\"`. Correto?

Comment: @IvanFerrer Fiz uma nova edição, por favor leia o que está escrito em cima do exemplo. Presta atenção somente que este código já bota aspas simples em volta do resultado, se preferir dá para tirar esta opção.

Comment: funcionou, só tive que trocar assim:  `var newVal = "\"" + escVal + "\";";`

Comment: @IvanFerrer Show! Boa sorte aí agora! :)

Answer (score 5):

Eu não sei se entendi bem o que você quer, porque não entendi a utilidade disto, mas acho que tudo que precisas é remover as quebras de linhas e espaços do texto.

```js
document.getElementById('btn-remover').addEventListener('click', fnClick);

function fnClick(){
  var val = document.getElementById('txt-css').value;
  val = val.replace(/[\s]/g, ' ');
  console.log(val);
}
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt-css"></textarea> <br>
<button id="btn-remover">Remover</button>
```

Comment: É quase isso, só que não deu certo.

Comment: ué, explique o que "não deu certo" então para o autor melhorar a resposta.

Comment: @IvanFerrer nesse caso você precisa detalhar o que não deu certo.

Comment: Pois é, eu tou ainda esperando o _feedback_ XD

Comment: O que não deu certo, o resultado do seu filtro, não dá pra colar entre aspas simples. o 'Edit' e o "Cancel" continuam com as mesmas aspas. Se for aspas simples, deveria ser 'Cancel' e \"Cancel\" ,inversamente, "Cancel"e '\Cancel\' .

Answer (score 0):

Talvez seja isso:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: blue; 
    color: red;
}
p {
    background-color: green; 
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the style properties of this document.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("STYLE")[0];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.innerHTML;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Fonte](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_get)

Comment: Sua resposta é interessante, porém, meu estilo está vindo de um arquivo style.css, então não tem como eu fazer desta forma.